# Existence of an Isometry of $\mathbb{R}^n$ onto Itself

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, isometry

For $a,b \in \mathbb{R}^n$, prove that there is an isometry of $\mathbb{R}^n$ onto itself which maps $a$ to $b$.

I am working with the following definition of an isometry:

Metric spaces $(X,d)$ and $(Y,d')$ are metrically equivalent, or isometric, if there is a one-to-one function $f:X \to Y$ from $X$ onto $Y$ such that for all $a,b \in X, \quad d(a,b) = d'(f(a),f(b))$.

Based on what I have read, maybe a particularly simple choice for a function to satisfy the above requirements will be the identity function $i: (X,d) \to (Y,d')$ since it is continuous. However, this seems like too simple of a solution since there is not much proof involved. Is this even the right way of approaching this problem? Any advice and suggestions will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't understand. The identity map $\Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R^n$ does not map $a$ to $b$ unless $a=b$.

Comment: Also, "since it is continuous" does not justify calling $i$ an isometry.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. Since continuity is not enough to call $i$ an isometry, how does one proceed to show that there is one?

Comment: Think in terms of geometry! Look at the plain, draw two points $a$ and $b$. What is an obvious mapping of the plain that maps $a$ to $b$?

Comment: Keep in mind, if you need to prove that a certain function exists satisfying certain properties, then you need to write down a formula for that function, however simple that may be (e.g. the answer of Brian Fitzpatrick), and then use that formula to show that the function has the properties it is supposed to have. There's no shortcut to existence proofs, you have to **show** the object.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint: Let $a,b\in\Bbb R$ and let $f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ be the map $f(x)=x+(b-a)$. Then $f(a)=b$. Is $f$ an isometry? Can this be generalized?

Let's develop this hint a bit more, first by showing that $f$ is indeed an isometry.

**Claim 1.** $f$ is invertible

*Proof.* Let $g:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ be the map $g(x)=x+(a-b)$. Then
\begin{align*}
f(g(x)) &= g(x)+(b-a) & g(f(x)) &= f(x)+(a-b) \\
&= x+(a-b)+(b-a) & &=x+(b-a)+(a-b) \\
&= x & &= x
\end{align*}
This proves that $f$ is invertible with $f^{-1}=g$. $\Box$

**Claim 2.** $\lVert f(x)- f(y)\rVert=\lVert x-y\rVert$

*Proof.* Note that
\begin{align*}
\lVert f(x)-f(y)\rVert
&= \big\lVert x+(b-a)-\big(y+(b-a)\big)\big\rVert \\
&= \lVert x+(b-a)-y-(b-a)\rVert \\
&= \lVert x-y\rVert
\end{align*}
as advertised. $\Box$

Do you see how Claim 1 and Claim 2 combined prove that $f$ is an isometry?

Comment: Ok, so I believe I was able to show that $f(x) = x+(b-a)$ is an isometry by showing it is one-to-one and onto. As for the proof regarding $d(a,b) = d'(f(a),f(b))$, does one just claim $|b-a| = |f(b)-f(a)|$?

Comment: You have to prove $d(x,y) = d'(f(x),f(y))$ for all $x,y$.  Not just for $a,b$.